# What is the difference between Symmetric vs Skew Symmetric?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I want to know the difference between `Symmetric Symmetric` vs `Skew Symmetric`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A symmetric matrix satisfies $A^T = A$

A skew-symmetric matrix satisfies $A^T = -A$.

Additionally, it is a fact that every matrix can be written as the sum of a symmetric matrix and a skew-symmetric matrix:

$$
A = \frac{1}{2}(A + A^T) + \frac{1}{2}(A - A^T)
$$

then $B = \frac{1}{2}(A + A^T)$ is symmetric since

$$
B^T = \frac{1}{2}(A + A^T)^T = \frac{1}{2}(A^T + A) = B
$$

and $C = \frac{1}{2}(A - A^T)$ is skew-symmetric:

$$
C^T = \frac{1}{2}(A - A^T)^T = \frac{1}{2}(A^T - A) = -C
$$

Answer (score 4):

$$
\mathbf{Symmetric}: \quad M^T=M
$$
$$
\mathbf{Skew\text{-}symmetric}: \quad M^T=-M
$$

Answer (score 0):

Skew-symmetric:

$A=-A^T$

Check out [this definition](http://www.math.ku.edu/~lerner/LAnotes/Chapter21.pdf)